# Unable to ping or rdp from UBUNTU 18.4.2. HOST to KVM windows7 Guest VM -but able to ping to other linux guest centos

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

Unable to ping to only Windows guest. able to ping to other guest.

HOST os Ubuntu 18.4.2

What i did so far-
Tried to change device to virtio,rtl8329,e1000

Internet is working on guest.

Windows 7 guest firewall disabled.

installed virtio driver for windows from -https://launchpad.net/kvm-guest-drivers-windows/+download

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2308987

from host able to ping to centos guest in same network and host.

Here is network configuration of host.

```
root@hp-e840-g1:/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq# ifconfig 
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::3832:b6ff:fed3:b592  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3a:32:b6:d3:b5:92  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1272  bytes 213475 (213.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br0:avahi: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.10.198  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        ether 3a:32:b6:d3:b5:92  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

enp0s25: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d0:bf:9c:1f:6d:7b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xd0700000-d0720000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 18229  bytes 1627449 (1.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 18229  bytes 1627449 (1.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:f6:8c:87  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 27291  bytes 1676922 (1.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21479  bytes 53057319 (53.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe63:38bc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:63:38:bc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 404  bytes 44813 (44.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 358  bytes 23713 (23.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe05:1413  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:05:14:13  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 634  bytes 50098 (50.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8973  bytes 667052 (667.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.10.5  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast 172.20.10.15
        inet6 fe80::2064:887d:4812:fd7d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ac:fd:ce:00:c4:6d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 105684  bytes 110034160 (110.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 70214  bytes 9358661 (9.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

any help really appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Thank you guys, the issue has been resolved by my self.

Windows 7  was blocking ICMP traffic, it was weird that i disabled firewall and service not no luck. ;)

After i enabled firewall rules to allow icmp packet then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, the issue has been resolved by my self.

Windows 7 was blocking ICMP traffic, it was weird that i disabled firewall and service not no luck. ;)

After i enabled firewall rules to allowed icmp packet then it worked.